# Trouble Detecting Method/Properites Typos in VSCode

Tags: javascript, jquery, visual-studio-code

I recently started working with web development using Visual Studio Code, coming from a Java background where typos in method/Property names would be immediately flagged as errors in my IDE (Eclipse). However, I've noticed that when working with Js/jQuery in VSCode, typos in method names don't seem to trigger any error.

I tested some extensions and searched around, but couldn't find a solution.

For instance, if I write:

`$("h1").textersr(event.key);`

Instead of:

`$("h1").text(event.key);`

VSCode doesn't flag this as an error. Is there a way to get VSCode to catch these typos? I want something like Eclipse's error detection in VSCode.

Comment: does VSC know what the return type of `$()` is?